# Como borrar un documento de una colección segun el objeto interno

Tags: mongodb, shell

de que forma en mongo Shell, puedo borrar un documento, segun el objeto que contiene

ejemplo:

```
[
  {
    "id": "5fd54ed43ba35c0448a4ba5c",
    "personaje": {
      "id": "25",
      "nombre": "Roberto",
      "createdAt": "2020-12-12 20:14:28"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "5fd54ed43ba35c0448a4ba5c",
    "personaje": {
      "id": "25",
      "nombre": "Benjamin",
      "createdAt": "2020-12-12 20:14:28"
    }
  }
]
```

y yo quisiera borrar el documento del objeto personaje que tenga el nombre "Benjamin"

Answer (score 0):

Se usa **la notación punto** para acceder a llaves de documentos embebidos:

> embedded_document.field

Solo reemplaza el nombre de tu colleción y ejecuta el siguiente método desde el mongo Shell:

```
db.nombreDeTuColl.deleteOne({"personaje.nombre":"Benjamin"})
```

Debe regresar algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Delete Doc Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/crud/delete#std-label-mongosh-delete)

[Docs Embebidos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation-embedded-fields)